# How to put an image from a div into an image tag?

Tags: jquery

I have a real problem.I am making a theme for WordPress.In a class I have a thumbnail with a big size.And I want to do some thing like this:

When user clicked on my class then i want to put the picture from that class into an image tag.
Some thing like this:

```
$("#big-gal-img").attr("src", $(this).children('.mgallery-image-big').val());
```

and this is my complete code:

```
<?php get_header();?>





<div id="big-gal-div">


 <div id="back-gal">
</div>
<img id="big-gal-img">
</div>



<center>
<div id="mgallery">
<div class="mGallery-Box">
    <?php query_posts ('');?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) :?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <div id="mone-in-gallery">
      <div class="mgallery-title"> 
        <a >
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="mgallery-image" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><a>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
        </a> 
      </div>
      <div class="mgallery-image-big"><a>
        <img class="mgallery-image-big" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail( full );?>">

        </a> 
      </div>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
 </div>
</div>
</center>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.mgallery-image-big').hide();
      $('#big-gal-div').hide();

   $('#big-gal-img').click(function(){
           $('#big-gal-div').hide();
       });

$('#mone-in-gallery').click(function(){
  var image_url = $('#mgallery-image-big').html();
         $("#big-gal-img").attr("src", $(this).children('.mgallery-image-big').val()); 
        $('#big-gal-div').show();
    });

});
</script> 



<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem... which problem are you *really* trying to solve? This seems to be just one approach to that problem.

Comment: I'll add my complete code.